# Grails service Spock test cant find file

Tags: web-services, grails, wsdl, spock

So Ive got a Grails 3.2.3 app, and in one of the services, I am loading a WSDL located in the root of my project folder to use with a SOAPClient like so:

```
def wsdl = "soap.wsdl"

    SOAPClient soapClient

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        soapClient = new SOAPClient(wsdl)
    }
```

My spock test is annotated with `@MockFor(MyService)` and Ive checked that the test runs the init method fine.

Now when the app is running, this creates the SOAPClient just fine, but when trying to write a Spock test, `new SOAPClient(wsdl)`returns null. Im guessing this is because when running the Spock test, the wsdl isnt properly in the classpath, but I havent found a way to solve this. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would metaClass the constructor of `SOAPClient` to return a mock of `SOAPClient`. Something like this:

`def 'test something'(){
    setup:
    def soapClientMock = Mock(SOAPClient)
    SOAPClient.metaclass.constructor = {String filename ->
        assert filename == "soap.wsdl"
        return soapClientMock
    }
}`